# png image make background color black in css ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I am using css with ionic . Using image in background but when i use image that maked background black.without image it looks fine.

```
ion-content {
    --background:  url("/assets/product_background.png") 0 0/100% 95% no-repeat;
--ion-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1a1240 35%,#6528af 70%,#736eed 100%);
}
```

`With Background image`

[image]

`without background image`

[image]

Comment: Have a look in your browser's dev tools inpecting the element to see what is overwriting what. Maybe you can put both backgrounds together and skip the ion setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add all of your properties to the `--background` value.

In your case:

`--background: url("/assets/product_background.png") 0 0/100% 95% no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #1a1240 35%, #6528af 70%, #736eed 100%);`

This will add your image and then include your gradient.